# CASE-WHEN condition without rewriting the whole statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I'll start of with a pseudo-code snippet:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN [very long expression] > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE [very long expression]
END
```

Is it possible to avoid rewriting the whole expression?

I already tried creating my own function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_isLargerThanOne(@v FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN
    IF(@v > 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @v = 1
    END
    RETURN @v
END
```

But using this function inside my query slows it down from 2s to 11s.
Any ideas?

Comment: also a tip when writing functions, always use an Inline Table Valued Function, if you must have a function, even if its to compute a scalar value, because they generally perform much better.

Comment: I do, which is why I tried to keep everything within my main function in a single statement (?)

Comment: Thats not an ITVF see [example B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I overread the part where you were talking about using it even when computing a scalar value, I'll try that. My main function (which I haven't posted here) is a ITVF though, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-query to compute the value which you want to use multiple times in the case expression e.g.

```
select
  CASE
    WHEN ComputedExpression > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE ComputedExpression
  END
from (
  select *, [very long expression] ComputedExpression
  from MyTable
) x
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for an elegant way in the line of
```php
if($val > 1)
{$val = 1;}
```
but I already suspected that won't be possible